# How to change modifier key to open new Firefox tab from URL

Tags: macos, firefox

In Safari and Chrome if I have focus in the URL field I can type Command Return to load the URL in a new tab. On Firefox it is Option Return. Is there a way to change Firefox to use Command instead of Option? about:config does not seem to have this listed.

This is Firefox 29 on Mac OS X 10.8.5

Answer (score 0):

Install this addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/customizable-shortcuts/

The addon will allow for you to modify all key shortcuts within Firefox. Next, go to your Options window. At the very right of the list of option categories, there should be a category called "Shortcuts". Open that, then find the key combination for new tabs and change it to your liking.

Comment: I don't see an option in this add-on to change this behavior.